# How to stream video via socket using OpenCV and picamera

Tags: camera, video

I'm relative new with Raspberry and I'm trying to stream a video to a PC using OpenCV libraries. I already made connection using the camera documentation but I don't know send the frames using OpenCV.

The code to stream to a network is:

```py
import socket
import time
import picamera

# Connect a client socket to my_server:8000 (change my_server to the
# hostname of your server)
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('my_server', 8000))

# Make a file-like object out of the connection
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
try:
     camera = picamera.PiCamera()
     camera.resolution = (640, 480)
     camera.framerate = 24
     # Start a preview and let the camera warm up for 2 seconds
     camera.start_preview()
     time.sleep(2)
     # Start recording, sending the output to the connection for 60
     # seconds, then stop
     camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264')
     camera.wait_recording(60)
     camera.stop_recording()
 finally:
     connection.close()
     client_socket.close()
```

And the code to stream to OpenCV object is:

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",          use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
         break
```

This code was not made by me, I need to thank Adrian for his tutorial from [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/).

Comment: OpenCV is an image processing library so you're not going to use it to send frames over the network. I'd recommend looking at the [capturing to a network stream](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-network-stream) recipe which goes through sending individual frames over a network socket. For more advanced usage, see the [Web streaming](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#web-streaming) recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of multi-platform and threaded [**VidGear**](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear) Video Processing python library that now provide [**NetGear API**](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/wiki/NetGear), which is exclusively designed to transfer video frames synchronously between interconnecting systems over the network in real-time. Here's a bare-minimum example to stream Picamera video:

#### A. Server End:(Bare-Minimum example)

Open your favorite terminal on your raspberry pi *(with Camera Module connected)* and execute the following python code:

**Tip:** *You can end streaming anytime on both server and client side by pressing [Ctrl+c] on your keyboard on the server's end!*

```py
# import libraries
from vidgear.gears import VideoGear
from vidgear.gears import NetGear

# enable enablePiCamera boolean flag to access PiGear API(Picamera) backend
stream = VideoGear(enablePiCamera=True).start()
server = NetGear() #Define netgear server with default settings

# infinite loop until [Ctrl+C] is pressed
while True:
    try: 
        frame = stream.read()
        # read frames

        # check if frame is None
        if frame is None:
            #if True break the infinite loop
            break

        # do something with frame here

        # send frame to server
        server.send(frame)
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        #break the infinite loop
        break

# safely close video stream
stream.stop()
# safely close server
writer.close()
```

#### B. Client End:(Bare-Minimum example)

Then open another terminal on the same system and execute the following python code and see the output:

```py
# import libraries
from vidgear.gears import NetGear
import cv2

#define netgear client with `receive_mode = True` and default settings
client = NetGear(receive_mode = True)

# infinite loop
while True:
    # receive frames from network
    frame = client.recv()

    # check if frame is None
    if frame is None:
        #if True break the infinite loop
        break

    # do something with frame here

    # Show output window
    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # check for 'q' key-press
    if key == ord("q"):
        #if 'q' key-pressed break out
        break

# close output window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# safely close client
client.close()
```

*NetGear currently supports three ZeroMQ messaging patterns: i.e `zmq.PAIR` and `zmq.REQ and zmq.REP` and  `zmq.PUB and zmq.SUB`. Whereas the supported protocol are: `'tcp', 'ipc'`*

**More advanced usage can be found here:** https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/netgear/overview/

- **Learn more about VideoGear here:** https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/videogear/overview/
- **Learn more about VidGear here:** https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear

Answer (score 5):

After months of searching the internet, this is what I came up with, I have neatly packaged it into classes, with unit tests and documentation as [SmoothStream](https://github.com/CT83/SmoothStream/) check it out, it was the only simple and working version of streaming I could find anywhere.

I used this code and wrapped mine around it.

Viewer.py

```
import cv2
import zmq
import base64
import numpy as np

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))

while True:
    try:
        frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
        img = base64.b64decode(frame)
        npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
        source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
        cv2.imshow("Stream", source)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Streamer.py

```
import base64
import cv2
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # init the camera

while True:
    try:
        grabbed, frame = camera.read()  # grab the current frame
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))  # resize the frame
        encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
        footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        camera.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```